# Как сделать обработчик события только на нужный слой?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте имеется 12 блоков при нажатии на блок тот открывается т.е к нему добавляется класс active.

И вот в этом блоке есть ещё несколько кнопок и проблема в том, что если нажать на любую из них, то событие, которое стоит на этом блоке срабатывает и блок закрывается. кнопка конечно же успевает сработать. я попробовал использовать event.stopPropagation() на кнопки, окно перестало закрываться, но fancybox привязанный к этим кнопкам тоже перестал нормально работать)

js

```
var scrollPosition = null;
$('.js-o-card').on('click', function () {
  var $window = $(window);
  const scrollAnimationDuration = 1000;
  if (!$(this).hasClass('active-card')) {

    $(this).addClass('active-card');

    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".active-card .thumbnail").offset().top - $(window).height() / 3
    }, scrollAnimationDuration);

    scrollPosition = $window.scrollTop();
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('active-card');

    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: scrollPosition
    }, scrollAnimationDuration);

  }
});
$('.js-btn-fancy').click(function(){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы такого не происходило?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать event.target.
Для примера:

```js
$('.wrapper').click(function(e){    
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON')
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
})

$('button').click(function(e){
    $(e.target).toggleClass('bg');
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;    
  background: blueviolet;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper button{
  display: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 5px;
}
  

.wrapper.active button{
  display: block;
}

button.bg{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">  
<h3>Card</h3>
  <button>Button1</button>
  <button>Button2</button>
  <button>Button3</button>
</div>
```